# Climb the ladder

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm playing in story mode. I have the digital deluxe edition and I have downloaded everything that comes with that.

I've been stuck on this for a long time. When I first purchased mass effect 3 I played it at a fairly casual pace for a bit and worked my way through soaking up the story exploring the gameplay and enjoying the graphics.

One day I hit a brick wall when I found that I could not progress any further. At the time I tried a search on on the internet to see if I could find out what to do, but I found nothing helpful.

Months have passed since then and I didn't play the game at all. So recently I decided to have another go, from the same place where I was stuck, and I am still stuck.

I cannot climb up a ladder. I have tried pressing the space bar but nothing happens. I'm quite sure that I need to climb up the ladder to continue.

Here is a screen shot of where the ladder is:

[image: mass effect 3 - ladder]

I can't remember where this is or what I was supposed to be doing there, but I do remember that I couldn't get up that ladder. The picture is a bit dark so you may need to look at the enlarged version to see the ladder, which is in between the two crew mates and to the right of the guy with the glowing forearm.

Here is a close up of the ladder:

[image: mass effect 3 - ladder up close]

Am I mistaken in thinking that I need to climb up this ladder? If so, what should I do to continue?

How can I progress further?

Should I start again? How can I get out of there?

Comment: This is the level where you are trying to help the Turians fight off the Reapers so that they will help you I believe.

Comment: I believe there is a part BEFORE you go up there, where you leave that camp from a different exit.
Is that Garrus in the top left of you first picture? Because if it is, you definitely ARE supposed to go up there.

Comment: Have your been to the broadcast tower yet? At the broadcast tower you have to send one up the tower (Liara was my choise) and the you and your partner defend while Liara fix the tower.

Comment: In a broader perspective, I simply think you should load your autosave, as this will take you back to your first arival at the moon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you are supposed to go up the ladder is if there is a 'blue arrow' attached to it and point up. This mission can be very confusing. Luckily, even though it is on several platforms there is really nothing exclusive in the missions so if you need help, regardless of what video walk through you watch, you will get help. 
If you search the internet do a specific search on Mass Effect 3 Turian Planet walk through.

The problem with this mission is that there are several exits and you need to find the right one to start a particular mission. So you will need to traverse the area thoroughly to find each area. You also might need to talk to several turians to start a particular mission - including defending the base and getting on that turret gun. A lot of things will not become active until you talk to someone. So double check by doing that.

I haven't been on this site in a while, so I don't remember if I am allowed to post links or not. 
The two youtube videos should help you - turn off the volume though. You only need to watch the gameplay. Yes you are spoiling the surprise gameplay, but remember your choices are your own and will infect your game in your own way. but check them out:

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to climb the ladder. You have just arrived on Menae, Palaven's largest moon, to find the Turian Primarch for a war summit with the Salarians and the Asari. Your first goal is to speak with General Corinthus. If that was done, then you need to head west of your position in the first screenshot to go repair a communications tower. You can either head that way and double back to the general if your path is blocked, or look in your journal to see what it says.